# Remove the newline after shell command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting, command-line

I have here the code:

```
#/bin/sh

cd ~/Desktop/tmp
date "+%m%d%y_%H%M%S_" | xargs -0 mkdir;
```

This will create a directory with the current date.
The problem here is that the `date` command will return a date with a newline character at the end.
After `mkdir`, the folder created will include a newline.
Anybody know how to go about this? I need a folder name without the newline character.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

why do you need to pass it to `xargs`? Don't do the unnecessary

```
mkdir $(date "+%m%d%y_%H%M%S_")
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason that the newline was included, is that you used the `-0` option, which makes xargs use null byte (ASCII 000) as a word boundary. Newlines are then included as part of the words. Dropping `-0` makes xargs use whitespace (including newline) as boundary, thus chopping it off.

However, use ghostdog74's solution, it's simpler.